# change in activity style deforms button

Tags: android, button, styles, android-actionbar

I want to change the style of my action bar (change the color and text font) and so set up my manifest and style XML as follows:

Manifest:(application)

```
android:theme="@style/ArbuckleAppTheme"
```

Style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ArbuckleAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/handler_noorder_startcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/handle_noorder_textcolor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The thing is one of my buttons (inside a sliding drawer) becomes much bigger. I tried changing layout values, etc. but to now avail.

Here is the xml surrounding the button:

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/bCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Cancel"
               android:background="@drawable/cancel_singleitem_background"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
```

There is an identical button in the main part of my app - which doesn't change shape.
I want to figure out why this one button's shape is getting completely screwed up. Happy to add more code if needed - thought I would start with immediate code first.

Comment: I just noted that when I type up my style in XML, autocomplete doesn't work with android:actionBarStyle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

You can remove the parent attribute from the application theme, and this removes the imposition of holo.light formatting across the entire app.

So the code is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ArbuckleAppTheme" >
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/handler_noorder_startcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/handle_noorder_textcolor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

By the way, the imposition I'm talking about (button becoming bigger) is because Google is trying to impose minimum standards on app development - and that includes buttons that are min. 48px.

I learned a lot from this - hope this is news to some of you so I can give back.